# Prevent an Android ActionBar tabs from switching in Xamarin

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android

I need to prevent an *ActionBar* tabs from switching based on a condition. *ActionBar.NavigationMode* is set to tabs mode. I see the following events available for each tab - *TabSelected*, *TabReselected* and *TabUnselected*, but there is no way to prevent the switching from their context. I also do not see any appropriate event for *ActionBar* either. I spotted some example of subclassing *TabHost* and overriding

> public void setCurrentTab(int currentTab);

but this didn't give a clue about *ActionBar* approach. 
Any ideas related to Xamarin or Android will be helpful.

NOTE: I want to intercept touches on the *ActionBar*, but conditionally decide should they be executed further.

Comment: Any way to disable tabs or the whole action bar?

Comment: @YuriS, Ask a separate question and I will try to help

Comment: This is not a question. This is suggestion how to disable switching but I am not sure if it is possible, that't why it is a comment and not an answer

Comment: @YuriS thanks for the suggestion! But check the note i've added.

Answer (score 0):

I see that those APIs were deprecated but if you have a legacy code...
Not sure if this is going to cause screen flicker but here is what you can try.

ActionBarTabsActivity

```
public class ActionBarTabsActivity : Activity
{
    ActionBar.Tab tab1, tab2;

    async public void UnselectedTab(ActionBar.Tab tab)
    {
        if (tab == tab2)
        {
            await Task.Run(() =>
            {
                RunOnUiThread(() => { ActionBar.SelectTab(tab); });
            });
        }
    }

    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);

        SetContentView(Resource.Layout.ActionBarTabsLayout);
        setupTabs();
    }

    private void setupTabs()
    {
        ActionBar.NavigationMode = ActionBarNavigationMode.Tabs;
        ActionBar.SetDisplayShowTitleEnabled(true);

        tab1 = ActionBar
            .NewTab()
            .SetText("First")
            //.SetIcon(R.drawable.ic_home)
            .SetTabListener(new ActionBarFragment1(this));

    ActionBar.AddTab(tab1);
    ActionBar.SelectTab(tab1);

        tab2 = ActionBar
        .NewTab()
        .SetText("Second")
        //.setIcon(R.drawable.ic_mentions)
            .SetTabListener(new ActionBarFragment1(this));

        ActionBar.AddTab(tab2);
    }
}
```

ActionBarFragment1

```
public class ActionBarFragment1 : Fragment, ITabListener
{
    ActionBarTabsActivity parent;

    public ActionBarFragment1(ActionBarTabsActivity parent)
    {
        this.parent = parent;
    }
    public override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);

        // Create your fragment here
    }

    public override View OnCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        // Use this to return your custom view for this Fragment
        return inflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.ActionBarFragmentLayout1, container, false);

    }

    public void OnTabReselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft)
    {
        //throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public void OnTabSelected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft)
    {
        //throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public void OnTabUnselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft)
    {
        parent.UnselectedTab(tab);
    }
}
```

Comment: @Kalitsov did this help?

Comment: I'm sorry the late response. This does not work for me. It doesn't prevent the navigation, but re-selects the desired tab. This leads to UI flickering. Thanks anyway!